# Plotly AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization

I'm trying to use Plotly to do a Displot for the returns for Apple stock in the past year.

```py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

hist_data = [df['Return'][1:]] 
group_labels = ['Apple Return distplot'] 

fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=.1)
fig.show()
```

And I got the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'show'

How can I resolve the above issue?

Comment: What version of `plotly` are you using?  Can you show us the output of `print(plotly.__file__)`?

Comment: @JohnGordon I got this message: `/Users/jacquelinewong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/__init__.py`

Comment: They have totally destroyed plotly. Nothing works for me too.

Answer (score 2):

If you're seeing this error, then you're using a version of `plotly` lower than 4.x and you will need to upgrade. I recommended upgrading to the latest version, which is 4.1.1

Comment: I upgraded to 4.1.1 but still got this message `ImportError: 
The plotly.plotly module is deprecated,
please install the chart-studio package and use the
chart_studio.plotly module instead. `

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Are you also importing from plotly.plotly? With version 4 this package moved, but it’s also no longer needed, specifically because fig.show() is the better way to show figures.

Comment: Is there any workaround, for those who cannot upgrade their plotly version?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```sh
!pip install plotly==4.1.1
```

```
from plotly import graph_objs as go
```